# Button Hover Effect

Tags: image, css, button

I'm quite new to CSS and web programming. What I'm trying to do is add a hovering effect for a button. I'm doing this by using 2 images.

There is a button called download and in hover code I add:

```
.button:hover{
    background-image:url(images/button2.png);

}
```

The problem is the button takes time to load ie: on hover there is a delay to show the button. How can i solve this?

EDIT: I tried using preloading,but there is also a kind of delay

```
div#preloadedImages
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
        background-image: url(images/button2.png);

}
```

Comment: try just background:url(images/button2.png)

Comment: Hey Asf, I created a working demo for you, the link is in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an image sprite to get rid of the delay. A sprite is one larger file that contains multiple images. Your button will have it's background set to sprite.png file. You can then change the `background-position` property to shift the positioning of your sprite.

On the other note - why do you use images for buttons? Most buttons can be done in pure CSS with some fallbacks for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single image out of the two images (which is called a sprite)

Here is a working example with an animation as well to show you how it works.

Click here >>> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/eAp2H/)

Then set your background position to to show the normal state of the background image

```
 .button {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url('image-sprite.jpg');
    background-position:  left top;
}
```

Then on your hover css, just move the background image to show the lower part of it

```
.button:hover {
    background-position: left bottom;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your current css and other stuff as they are and add an `<img>` component at anywhere of your page and make it hidden to load the image initially.

```
<img src="images/button2.png" style="display:none;"/>
```